# better approach to intialise properties of init method in java @configuration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a dependency of ExternalContext class which is defined as below. **Dependency is added by jar, so modification not allowed.**

```
public class ExternalContext {

    private String emailUsername;
    private String emailPassword;
    // setters & getters
    private InitialContext initialContext;

    public void init() {
            Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();

            if (!(emailUsername == null)) {
                props.put("SEC_PRINCIPAL", emailUsername);
            }
            if (emailPassword != null) {
                props.put("SEC_CREDENTIALS", emailPassword);
            }
            initialContext = new InitialContext(props);
    }
}
```

I need to create bean of above class and also initialize properties by calling it's init method. This is how I am trying to do

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${email.username}")
    private String emailUsername;

    @Value("${email.password}")
    private String password;

    private final PasswordDecryptor passwordDecryptor;

    public AppConfig(PasswordDecryptor passwordDecryptor) {
        this.passwordDecryptor = passwordDecryptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public String emailPassword(){
        return passwordDecryptor.decrypt(password);
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "init" )
    public ExternalContext externalContext(){
        return new ExternalContext();
    }
}
```

I have created bean of emailPassword so that value is available when init method of ExternalContext class is called.

**Is there any better approach of initializing property in this scenario?**

**Is there any alternative where I need not to create bean of emailPassword?**

I am using spring boot 2.1.15.RELEASE

Comment: The `ExternalContext` snippet does not display how the `emailUsername` and `emailPassword` fields are being filled. Is there a constructor available, or is it explicitly searching for two **String** beans **named** `emailUsername` and `emailPassword` ?

Comment: @Michiel Setters/Getters are present to set the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, create an object, fill fields and call `init()`:

```
@Bean
public ExternalContext externalContext() {
    ExternalContext ctx = new ExternalContext();
    ctx.setEmailUsername(emailUsername);
    ctx.setEmailPassword(passwordDecryptor.decrypt(password));
    ctx.init();
    return ctx;
}
```